# i can't use (point_distance) to kill any enemy nearset my hero GMK

Tags: xcode, game-maker, gml

I have a problem with a code in the Game Maker program
I make a little game that has a path that the enemies walk on and put heroes on his side and when the enemy approaches him he turns to him and he shoots him
I am using this code

```
var ex, ey;
ex = instance_nearest(x, y, enemy).x;
ey = instance_nearest(x, y, enemy).y;

if point_distance(x, y, ex, ey) < 150
{
     image_angle = point_direction(x, y, enemy.x, enemy.y);
}
```

The code works well, but the problem is that my heroes only go to the first enemy when they come close to them and do not go to the rest even when the first enemy is out of range
What is the solution, please
Photo for illustration
 [Heroes ignore the nearby enemy and only head for the first enemy to appear in the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRmIb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the correct enemy but not pointing at the correct enemy. Store the found instance ID instead, and use it for all:

```
var e;
e = instance_nearest(x, y, enemy);
if (e != noone) { // wouldn't want to crash when you run out of enemies
    if (point_distance(x, y, e.x, e.y) < 150) {
        image_angle = point_direction(x, y, e.x, e.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer gave by YellowAfterlife solved the problem. But not sure if the reason of the problem was clear, then I want to complement by explain that the problem happened because the code in "point_direction" is referencing the **object** instead of the **instance**.

The **object** is the template that the created instance is based of, if you want to manipulate or get information you should reference the **instance**. If you only have one **instance** of that **object**, it will work referencing the **object** directly, but after more were created, it will return the index of only one of them (maybe the first created).

*About **instances**: every **object** that you drag to the room will became an **instance** of that object or when you create an **instance** from the code, like calling "instance_create_layer(x, y, "instance_layer", obj_Bullet)", this function will return  the reference/index of the new **instance** created.*

When the function "instance_nearest" is called it receives the player **instance** position (x and y) and the **object** of the **instances** that you want to check if it's near to the player, for example, the enemy object. The function will check all **instances** that was created from the informed **object** and will returns the index/reference of the **instance** nearest to the player. In the original code when calling the point_direction, was used the object enemy instead of the instance returned by instance_nearest function.

The **object** will always return the same index of some instance, causing the problem reported, that the player instance always point to the same enemy instance (coincidentally, the first instance created)

You can use the **object** if want to manipulate all **instances** at once, like this: "with(o_player) y++;". This code will make all **instances** of that object move down together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `collision_circle_list(...)`.
This function will get you a list of all objects that collide within that circle and you can iterate through them to find which is closest, furthest, etc.

Resource:
https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/collision_circle_list.html